# Modeling Telecommunications Infrastructure in GIS?

Tags: references, telecom, arcgis-data-model

I am looking for resources that will help me to model telecommunications infrastructure of a small town/campus in GIS.  Can anyone suggest where to look for:

1. A telecommunications GIS data model (I know ESRI created one)
2. Place on the web (e.g. forum, group) that this is being discussed or could be a helpful resource.

Answer (score 5):

Telvent has a fiber manager that uses a pretty in depth model. I have looked a bit but don't see a complete description of the model. Links provided are just some overviews of the model.
It might be overkill for what you are doing but their other data models for utilies are very nice.
[Overview](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/DesktopConfig/FiberManagerOverview.html)
[simplified model Page 8](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/egug2007/papers/tuesday/am/d_managing-fiber.pdf)
[Object classes and field names](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/DesktopConfig/FM_AddModelNames.html)

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I thought there might be a non-proprietary data model that could possibly even be a collaborative project.  I wonder what managers of smaller networks (e.g. college campuses) are doing to model and manage their network.

Comment: I would almost bet that when they get small they use autocad or map3d. I do know that CH Guernsey used to have sell services for telecoms and they had their own autocad system (with vb customization) that they used to manage the services. They had an "in-plant" and outside-plant setup, but I am sure there was no real work done as toward a model. Are you familiar with uml modeling? You might develop from what I have shown in visio and then port that to uml.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea.  It looks similar to the ESRI telecomm data model, which ESRI provides in Visio.  Unfortunately it only includes fiber related elements and not copper.  So I will look into adding fiber elements to it.  The data model uses relationship classes, which adds some complexity when making any changes.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is of interest: **GRASS GIS RaPlaT** - *The Radio Planning Tool for GRASS GIS* system developed by support of Slovenian largest mobile operator Mobitel. It is especially designed for radio coverage calculation of GSM/UMTS systems, but can be applied also to other wireless systems in the frequency range 400 MHz – 2.4 GHz (e.g. TETRA, WiFi). Its structure is modular and characterized by high level of flexibility and adaptability.

- Documentation: http://commsys.ijs.si/en/component/content/article/54-software/149-user-manual
- Software: http://commsys.ijs.si/en/software/grass-raplat

Author: Department of Communication Systems, Jozef Stefan Institue, Jamova 39, SI-1000 Ljubljana, Slovenia

Answer (score -1):

Smallworld has got an extensive suite of telecomms applications - Smallworld Network Inventory - that targets most aspects of telcommunications industry, both physical and logical infrastructure. This truly a very advanced group of applications, if this is what you are looking for.

You can find a short overview here: http://www.slideshare.net/cwilson5496/ge-smallworld-overview-september2010

Comment: As a Smallworld User I can state, that Smallworld might make sense to manage the infrastructures of whole countries, but in my opinion using it for 'small towns/campus' is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut - quite apart from the exorbitant license fees they have.